# DateFormatter does NOT convert specific dates (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

I have the below code on playground and app and DateFormatter are returning nil just for the date "1990-10-21":

---

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"

let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: "1990-10-20") // "Oct 20, 1990 at 12:00 AM"
let date2 = dateFormatter.date(from: "1990-10-21") // nil
let date3 = dateFormatter.date(from: "1990-10-22") // "Oct 22, 1990 at 12:00 AM"
```

---

Testing with 1989, 2021... works fine...

Does anyone knows why or something about this? is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three issues with your code. First `YYYY` is for [`YearForWeekOfYear`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatecomponents/1413809-yearforweekofyear). What you need is `yyyy`. Second you are not passing the time. Note that not all days starts at `12:00am` (daylight savings transition dates). You can prevent the date formatter returning `nil` by setting its calendar or passing a valid time (12pm) along with the date. Third you should always set the locale to `"en_US_POSIX"` when using a fixed date format:

---

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.calendar = .current
dateFormatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: "1990-10-20") // "Oct 20, 1990 at 12:00 AM"
let date2 = dateFormatter.date(from: "1990-10-21") // "Oct 21, 1990 at 1:00 AM"
let date3 = dateFormatter.date(from: "1990-10-22") // "Oct 22, 1990 at 12:00 AM"
```

Comment: I'm using locale on my code, just removed here and playground because it didn't affect the problem.  
I tried yyyy but it also didn't affect the problem, but I understand what you mean and I will keep using yyyy.
Setting the calendar is something I never try and solved it. Thanks

Comment: YYYY would give you wrong results on dates close to the new year